# reactivating ubuntu after windows install

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, restore

I installed unbuntu from a live CD in order to save some data from the windows OS previously installed on my computer. Now I've reinstalled windows, but I don't see the grub menu, in order to choose which OS to run.

Does anyone knows how can I have access to that menu and later to the ubuntu OS already installed?

Answer (score 1):

You mean GRUB? Ubuntu comes with GRUB and not LILO.

Anyway, [here is a documentation on how to install GRUB2 from a Live-CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2), and if you're really using LILO, the steps should be identical, except that you have to install LILO instead of GRUB.

Comment: your right, not lilo, it's about grub, but how to install it on my machine from a live CD?

Comment: @doug: How about the link I posted?

Answer (score 1):

This should help you :
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows